# Hide Status Bar but display action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, statusbar

Status bar is where battery,time is displayed and action bar is title bar.I want to hide status bar in my app but display action bar.Is it possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Write the following in Activity after onCreate:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Here is screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Ok, buw how can I avoid status bar expansion with swipe gesture?

Comment: Do you happen to know why Google emphasizes "you should never show the action bar if the status bar is hidden".  I do not see any problem with an action bar without the status bar.  I cannot figure out their reason.

Comment: can we do the same from `styles.xml`? so that it applies to all activities

Comment: @Prags you can't without also hiding the Action Bar. If you're okay with not hiding the ActionBar, you should be able to find a "FULLSCREEN" base style that will remove both the Status Bar and the Action Bar. Something like `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">`.